# What element can I use around my content to eliminate wrapping?

Tags: html

I'm very new to html and I was wondering if there is anything I can use other than a div element. The code that I want to use displays a hover. For example: `<div id="cartpopup">`.

Well this makes it so whatever I put in between these tags gets lowered. Everything is working fine I just don't want my image to be lowered because of div. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: show code of what you're doing. a div in most cases is best practice to use. however there is no real requirement to use it.. just a good idea

Comment: Post the code or show us on http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: @AhmadSharif Adding a `<div>` above an `<img>` pushes the image down, the OP want's to know how to prevent that.

Comment: Okay I've figured it out, just a few problems in my stylesheet! Thank you everyone!

Comment: Bryce, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn what's expected of you when you ask a question. Then, provide and/or accept an answer to resolve this post. Abandoned questions are ugly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent line wrapping, try using a `span` element, which is inline.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

You could also set a div to display inline or inline-block (which allows CSS sizing, for example) using CSS:

```
#cartpopup {display: inline-block;}
```